# Use gradle to change App Environment ( development/ production...) automatically

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, environment

I am developing android application.In the app, I need to have multiple servers such as development, staging and production. For each environment, I had to specify others sensitive keys as well. I am changing flag for each environment manually it for now. I want to use gradle to automate this. According to gradle documentation , there is a terms called **build type** such as **release** and **debug** by default. There is also **product flavours**. I am not sure which one to use and how to. Any advice would be appreciate.

***This is how i change App env in Application.java***

```
public static final int APP_ENV = 2;//2 => dev, 1 => staging, 0 => production
```

***This is how I differentiate url and other keys***

```
switch (envVar){
            case DEV :
                url ="http://a.com";
                google_analytic_id="aaaa..";
                ....
                break;
            case STAG :
                url = "http://b.com";
                google_analytic_id="bbbb..";
                .....
                break;
            case PRO :
                google_analytic_id="cccc..";
                .....
                break;
            default:
                url ="http://a.com";
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use flavours for this.  A partial `build.gradle` file might look like:

```
productFlavors {
  production {
    buildConfigField 'String', 'URL', '"http://a.com"'
  }
  development {
      buildConfigField 'String', 'URL', '"http://b.com"'
  }
}
```

which will populate `BuildConfig.java` with the information you provided.  Then in your Java code you can do things like:

```
System.out.println("My URL is " + BuildConfig.URL);
```

And you can create your particular build with:

```
gradle assembleProductionDebug
```

or

```
gradle assembleDevelopmentDebug
```

(where you can switch Debug for Release as required).

Details of how to use product flavours is available at http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

Comment: Appreciate for the answer , i am going to give it a try. Thanks thanks

Comment: Woh it worked perfectly . Is there a way to get these url from app properties file ? instead of hardcore in gradle file

Comment: You can create different directories for the product flavors and it will use them.  So where you currently have `src/main/resources/app.properties` you could instead have `src/production/resources/app.properties` and `src/development/resources/app.properties` and gradle will pick up the correct file for the flavor.

Comment: can you provide some example for that ? thank you so much @jgm

Comment: There's not really anything more to show beyond what is written in the previous comment.  The underlying principle is that the source tree for compilation and creation of the APK starts with /src/main and then anything in /src/{flavor} is added to the tree, either adding to or overwriting what was in /src/main.

Comment: I mean how can I include app.properties into gradle and use it attributes. how gralde automatically detect app.properties file ?

Comment: You need to put them in an `assets` directory so `src/development/assets/app.properties` and `src/production/assets/app.properties`, then access them in your code with `getBaseContext().getAssets().open("app.properties")`

Comment: Ohh i see what you are pointing out. Thanks thanks i applied ur advise and now seem okay . :-)